# Meteor - webpack and ecmascript are both trying to handle *.jsx

Tags: reactjs, meteor, webpack, ecmascript-6

So I'm trying to install and use [react-wavesurfer](https://github.com/mspae/react-wavesurfer) in Meteor which is a react component wrapper for an existing js library ([wavesurfer.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavesurfer.js)). It requires that the wavesurfer.js file (which has to be installed separately) is made available as a global variable.

The suggestion is to use webpack for this as below :

```
// provide WaveSurfer as a globally accessible variable
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    WaveSurfer: 'wavesurfer.js'
  })
],
// Alias `wavesurfer` to the correct wavesurfer package.
// (wavesurfer.js has some non-standard naming convention)
resolve: {
  alias: {
    wavesurfer: require.resolve('wavesurfer.js')
  }
},
```

I've never used Webpack (not entirely sure what it does) and I'm a Meteor / React newbie.

So I installed :

```
meteor add webpack:webpack
```

And now I'm getting the following error in the console :

```
While determining active plugins:
error: conflict: two packages included in the app (webpack:webpack and ecmascript) are both trying to handle *.js
error: conflict: two packages included in the app (webpack:webpack and ecmascript) are both trying to handle *.jsx
```

From the error I assume that `ecmascript` (again something I know nothing about) is doing a similar job to webpack already which is causing the clash?

So, my question... How do I set this up using `ecmascript` instead? I literally have no idea!

Comment: Hmmm.. So I simply threw `WaveSurfer = require('wavesurfer.js');` in `client.js` and it's working! Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use new package that I still maintain
https://github.com/ardatan/meteor-webpack